# MySQL:Case Statement Issue

Tags: mysql

Complaint_status Table : multiple rows for a complaints

```
id  complaint_id  status_type  status_value
 1            11            2             0
 2            11            2             2
 3            11            2             1
 4            11            2             2
```

Trying to get `min(id)` having `status_type=2` and `status_value=2` but showing `null`,have to use case statement for doing other stuff.

```
SELECT c3.id AS Ticket_id,
       CASE
           WHEN cs.status_value=2 THEN cs.created_at
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Closure_date
FROM complaint c3
INNER JOIN complaint_status cs ON cs.complaint_id=c3.id
WHERE cs.id IN
    (SELECT min(id)
     FROM complaint3_status
     WHERE complaint_id=c3.id
       AND status_type=2)
  AND c3.id IN(11)
```

Comment: You don't need a case.

Comment: "have to use `case` statement for doing other stuff"?  Your question is incomplete.

Comment: i Have to use CASE statement,will calculate aging on basic of status

Comment: For example when status_type=2 then aging=now()-(status type 2 creation date)....and when status_type =1 then aging=now()-(status type 1 creation date)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that gives you the entire row:

```
select cs.*
from complaint_status cs
where status_type = 2 and status_value = 2
order by id asc
limit 1;
```

You can just use `select id` if that is all you want.  I have no idea what `case` has to do with this query.